# Script that will open a file, edit and save with the same file name

Tags: python-2.7

I have a simple script I'm working on that will have the user enter in a few variables such as, Year, Make, Model, Miles. Once the variables are entered it will open the cars.txt and add it to the list and save the file.

I think I have most of it basically written and I'm almost positive the structure is wrong, but the issue I'm running into is writing the variables in a list after all the info is entered.

```
print "Enter Year"  
year = raw_input()

print "Enter Make"  
make = raw_input()

print "Enter Model"  
model = raw_input()

print "Enter Mileage"  
mile = raw_input()

print "new vehicle added: (year), (make), (model), (mile)"

fo = open("cars.txt", "a")
fo.write("(year), (make), (model), (mile)");
fo.close()
```

when it prints the output and writes the file, i doesn't enter the variables I've had them enter. it just puts (year) or (mile).

Again I'm completely new to this and am figuring this out as i research and learn. Thanks in advance for and help or advice.

Comment: Did you tried something by yourself first?

Comment: Can you give us your code?

Comment: Sorry guys, it was 3am i edited it to show the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just give a try to this simple code.

```
fo = open("cars.txt", "a")
fo.write( "2015,Honda,Civic,105,000mi");
fo.close()
```

If you want any help regarding this you can get it here or if you are new to this you can even learn it here [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the response Kedar! What an awful question i gave you. I have that part down already. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you put quotation marks around your variables. Python thinks that you want to add a set of strings to your file!

Instead of `print "new vehicle added: (year), (make), (model), (mile)"`

Try  `print "new vehicle added: " year + make + mode + mile`

Instead of `fo.write("(year), (make), (model), (mile)");`

Try  `fo.write(year + make + model + mile);`

EDIT: I have also made it so that the content displayed inside text file has some nice formatting, so instead of adding the code above try adding this instead

```
car = make + model
fo.write(car + " : " year + mile);
```